# When using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream to transfer a custom object the variables are reset

Tags: java, networking, stream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have created a server-client chat room style application and I'm trying to transfer a custom object which I have created containing the message and the username of the person using client/server application. To do this I have created a separate class called `message` which contains two static variables, one called `username` and one called `messageText`:

```
public class message implements Serializable{

    static String username = "";
    static String messageText = "";

    public message(String message, String user){
        System.out.println("Setting username and messageText");
        username = user;
        messageText = message;
    }

    public message(Object recievedObject){
        username = ((message) recievedObject).getUsername();
        messageText = ((message) recievedObject).getMessageText();
    }
}
```

I send an object of this class from my server to a client as follows:

```
message sendMessage = new message(enteredText, "SERVER");
output.writeObject(sendMessage);
```

It is accepted by the client as follows:

```
message recievedMessage = (message) input.readObject();
cw.say(recievedMessage.getMessageText(), recievedMessage.getUsername());
```

However both methods above `getMessageText()` and `getUsername()` will return whatever the variable was initialized with on the receiving end, and return the correct values on the sending side.

A few hours of trying to fix this problem has provided no solution, so any help that you guys can give me is very, very appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Static variables are not serialized.

Comment: Elliot, you've fixed my problem :)

Comment: ... also those marked as transient ... besides of that it looks like a design flaw, you don't want all objects of that class to share the same username and message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static fields are not serialized. If you make them non-static it should work

Comment: +1 and call `reset()` on the output stream so it sends the contents again.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are shared by all instances of a class. That means it doesn't make much sense to serialize them.

In a message, the fields "username" and "messageText" are likely not meant to be static, unless there is only one message in existence.